# A question about compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $C(X)$ be the set of continuous functions on $X$. And $F$ is a closed subspace of $X$. If the $f\in C(X)$ such that $f|_{F}=0$ is only zero function( i.e. $f=0$), then $F=X$???

Comment: Are you talking about functions to $\mathbb{R}$ here? I advice you to make that explicit. Functions 'on' $X$ are often interpreted as functions from $X$ to $X$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, by Urysohn's Lemma : If $F \neq X$, then there is some $x\in X\setminus F$, and a continuous function $f$ such that $f(x) = 1$, and $f = 0$ on $F$.

Comment: Thanks Prahlad Vaidyanathan. :)